# Failed to resolve: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to integrate volly library, but I got always same error

```
Error:(15, 13) Failed to resolve: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19
```

Here is my build.gradle : http://pastebin.com/FF3N8VFE

Someone faced the issue before? I see many projects using it without any problems :(

Thanks for helping

Comment: I suggest you to use `OkHttp` rather than volley

Answer (score 0):

I met problems, like you, maybe you should add this!

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's deprecated and not updated.

[DEPRECATED](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

Please note, this project is deprecated and no longer being maintained, please use official version.

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```